# When checkbox is selected multiply textbox value by 0.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a non-clickable textbox that I am using to keep a running total (everytime a checkbox is clicked, it's value is being added to the textbox).

I am struggling however with doing some multiplication on this textbox value. I have a checkbox that, when selected, I would like to multiply by 0.9 (to simulate a 10% discount). How would I go about doing this?

Here's what I have so far (but is not working - textbox value just goes to 0.00):

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
      var sum = 0;
      $('input[id=10percent]').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('input[id=15percent]:checked').each(function() {
        debugger;
          var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
          sum * 0.9;
        });
        $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2));
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="runningtotal">
Running CPC Total (in £): <input id='sum' type='text' readonly />
</div>
HTML (for radio boxes):

<div class="agencydiscount">
    <h1>Agency Discount</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" value="0.00">None<br>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.00">10% Discount<br>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.00">15% Discount<br>
</div>
jQuery:
```

jQuery to update running total textbox:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var sum = 0;
      $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        debugger;
          var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
          sum += val;
        });
        $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2));
      });
    });
```

Comment: what is this supposed to do? ... `sum * 0.9;`

Comment: @jsotola multiply the current value of the textbox by 0.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JS seems a little confused. You're attaching only one event handler and trying to loop over an unrelated selector that contains only a single element. You're also multiplying the value but not assigning the result to anything.

To make this work you need to attach the event handler to *all* the radio buttons. Then you can use the `value` property of all the radios to hold the number to multiply the `#sum` by to get the discounted total.

Also note that you need somewhere to store the original total, ie. the value *before* any discount is applied, so that the calculation always works from the base figure. You can use a `data` attribute for this, but note that you *must* update this attribute along with the value.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;        
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });
  
  function applyDiscount() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    $('#sum').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="10.00">
  £10.00
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5.00">
  £5.00
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="19.99">
  £19.99
</label>

<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id="sum" type="text" readonly="true" value="0.00" data-total="0" />
</div>

<div class="agencydiscount">
  <h1>Agency Discount</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" value="1" checked>
    None
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.9">
    10% Discount
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.85">
    15% Discount
  </label>
</div>
```

As an aside, I would suggest researching the basics of JS as there's some fundamental principles you need to get a firm grasp of. This [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) is a great starter.

Comment: this only performs the calculations based off the data value 1000 you've assigned to the textbox, but this value will constantly be changing based on which checkboxes are selected?

Comment: That's correct. As I mentioned in the question, when the value is changed you need to ensure you also update the `data-total` so that the original value is saved somewhere for the calculations to work from.

Comment: oh I see, apologies. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Well I assume you're calling `$('#sum').val(N)` at some point? At the same time set `data('total', N)` too

Comment: apologies again I'm a little lost now! where should I be calling `$('#sum').val(N)`? Outside of this function?

Comment: I don't know how to make this clearer. From the comment above state you are updating the value of `#sum` when someone checks a checkbox. All you need to do when that happens is also update the `data-total` of the textbox as you set its `val()`. If you're struggling with this please add the relevant code to the question and I'll show you how you need to do this.

Comment: I've just updated the question with my additional jquery code for adding checkbox values to running total textbox

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer to show you how to do it. Also note that I extracted the discount calculation logic in to its own function as you'll need to call it both when the value changes and also when a new discount value is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206920/discussion-between-bboooooyintheuk-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 0):

You must use their name instead of using their id. So your code must be like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var sum = $('input[name=percentdiscount]:checked').attr('value') * 0.9;
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id='sum' type='text' readonly />
</div>

<div class="agencydiscount">
  <h1>Agency Discount</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" value="0.00">None<br>
  <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="10.00">10% Discount<br>
  <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="20.00">15% Discount<br>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right - you've hard coded values to the discount percentages and then outputting 90% of that arbitrary value.

Comment: Its just a sample about his problem. I just gave him the logic. There's noting to worry about @RoryMcCrossan